# Kubernetes and get data from SQL into a different server

Tags: sql, docker, kubernetes

I have a set of servers in VMWARE part with windows and part with linux. 
I have created using some ubuntu servers (16.04.5) a Kubernetes environment with 1 MASTER 2 NODES.
Everything is working work fine but i got stuck when i created a CONTAINER with DOCKER that i after inserted inside a POD on Kubernetes where i was asking data from a SQL SERVER 2012.
The script on my local pc works fine, and inside a docker container also,  is when I put it inside the pod on kubernetes that i have issues. 
I get to the container with the KUBERNETES SERVICE that works fine but when i call the .py script to get the data from SQL into the LOG i find:

Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (                                                                   <"IP of mine SQL">:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Connection timed out (110)\n')

And the strange thing is that on the beginning of the log i find the data from SQL, so it looks like, it execute the script it get the data, than it change status and it doesn't like the IP any more.

I don't udnerstand what actually is going on... Any help?

Thanks

s

Answer (score 1):

If your container able to access DB server first time, there is not reason to fail after wards. 
Still check if your pod is still up and running and also check DB server is really accessible from container.Just go to container with below command and ping DB server.

```
kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> bash
ping DB_SERVER_HOST
```

If this is working, its issue with your script only.

Comment: ping done 31 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 30016ms
at this point is the pod blocking the connection. I don't think that the kube Service matters on this. Or am I wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: Pod never blocks connection. Check you are using correct db host name.  if it is having  any domain name, use that as one as prefix. I faced similar situation when I was not able to pind db host and reason was I was not using domain name as prefix.

Comment: I tried also to ping www.google.com inside the pod there is no way to get anywhere. it looks like there are no open ports to get out of the pod. Do you know how can i change or check the connectivity, ports or network setting of the pod? tks!

Comment: Check if your admin created NetworkPolicy for your cluster. By default pods should not block.

Comment: I'm the only one working on it and i didn't setup any network policy. I have been reding the following:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Nothing has been done so by default it shuld be fine... i don't understand what is blocking the connection.